# Specify file from list, check file size, if GTR 1MB > check extension, if .doc do copy

Tags: batch-file, filesize

I need your help.

I have thousands of documents (.doc) saved in multiple folders within one location. I need a batch script to help me with the following:

```
Grab file name from list.txt 
Search for file within source directory and sub-directories 
When found, check file size 
If GTR 1MB do Copy to Destination without retaining folder structure 
If LT 1MB do nothing and move on to next file on list
```

I am a beginner when it comes to scripting and everything seems so confusing to me. So far from all the research I carried out I have the following but it does nothing, CMD just opens and instantly closes when I run it.

Could someone kindly point me in the right direction to achieve the result which I am looking for. Where is a good place to learn more about batch scripting as I can see I will have more use for it in the future.

Thank you in advance for any responses.

```
@Echo off

set filelist="C:\Users\Me\Desktop\User Data\list.txt"
set source="C:\Users\Me\Desktop\User Data"
set destination="H:\New Folder\User Data Backup"
set maxbytesize=1000000

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in "%filelist%" DO (
    xcopy /S /E /U "%source%\%%i" "%destination%"
)

pause
```

Comment: What if a file is found muliple times within your source directory tree?

Comment: I am a 100% certain that there will be no duplicate file names as this would cause issues within our EPR system therefore we do not need to worry about coding that part.

Comment: What should happen in case a file is exactly 1000000 bytes big? copy or not?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite

```
set filelist="C:\Users\Me\Desktop\User Data\list.txt"
```

as

```
set "filelist=C:\Users\Me\Desktop\User Data\list.txt"
```

The first assigns the text *including the quotes* **AND** *any trailing spaces* to the variable. The second assigns only that part between the `=` and the closing quote.

(obviously, this needs to be corrected for every **string**-assignment instance.)

With your code, your `for` command becomes

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ""C:\Users\Me\Desktop\User Data\list.txt"" DO (
```

(the `%var%` is simply and mechanically replaced by that variable's value)

Which is incorrect on two counts - the doubling of the quotes and the missing parentheses. The `for` command is

```
for %%x in (set) do
```

Hence, batch detects and reports a syntax error, but since you're evidently using point-click and giggle, the window automatically closes having produced the error message.

There are many SO items about how to set up a command-prompt session. It's a lot easier to  use "DOS" (it's not really DOS - it's a DOS emulator with enhancements) "from the prompt"

Meanwhile, try (after fixing the quotes)

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%filelist%) DO (
    IF %%~zi geq %maxbytesize% xcopy /S /E /U "%source%\%%i" "%destination%"
)
```

Note however that if `filelist` contains spaces, you'd need

```
for /f "usebackqtokens=*" %%i in ("%filelist%") DO (
```

and your code is only looking for your list of filenames in your *current* directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt which should hopefully copy all found files incrementing file names for those already existing in the destination.

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "srcDir=%UserProfile%\Desktop\User Data"
Set "dstDir=H:\New Folder\User Data Backup"
Set "lstTxt=%UserProfile%\Desktop\User Data\list.txt"
Set "minSiz=1048576"

For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("%lstTxt%"
) Do For /F "Tokens=1,3*" %%B In ('Where/T /F /R "%srcDir%" "%%~nxA" 2^>Nul'
) Do If %%B Gtr %minSiz% If Not Exist "%dstDir%\%%~nxA" (Copy %%D "%dstDir%">Nul
) Else Cmd/Q /S /C"For /L %%E In (1 1 9999) Do If Not Exist "%dstDir%\%%~nA[%%E]%%~xA" Copy %%D "%dstDir%\%%~nA[%%E]%%~xA">Nul&&Exit"
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the quotation and syntax issues already out by [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44103196), I fixed an issue concerning the path depth as you want to copy the matching files without their folder structure:

```cmd
@echo off

set "filelist=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\User Data\list.txt"
set "source=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\User Data"
set "destination=H:\New Folder\User Data Backup"
set "maxbytesize=1000000"

for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in ("%filelist%") do (
    for /F "delims=" %%j in ('dir /B /S /A:-D "%source%\%%i"') do (
        if %%~zj GTR %maxbytesize% copy "%%j" "%destination%\"
    )
)

pause
```

I replaced `xcopy /U` by `copy`, because the former command copies only files that already exist in the destination, which I assume is not what you want.